# JMeter - Script creation for Desktop application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Am trying to simulate a desktop application via JMeter. Tried recording the traffic. It isn't capturing all the requests. The scenario is

```
   1. Launch the exe file.
   2. Login.
   3. Switch Tabs.
   4. Logout.
```

Need to capture the above steps into individual transaction controllers.

May be some groovy script like:

```
   1. Note the current time (T1).
   2. Launch the file.
   3. Note the current time (T2).
   4. Login.
   5. Note the current time (T3).
   6. So, response time for launch will be (T2-T1).
   7. Login Response Time will be (T3-T2).
```

might help. Could someone help me with this? Screenshots for the steps are attached.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,

[Double Click on the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfxY5.jpg)

[Launch Page - Enter the credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYvYP.jpg)

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM2Mo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide what exactly you need to do.

1. You need to simulate hundreds/thousands of desktop applications which are concurrently accessing the backend. In this case you need to use relevant Samplers or Plugins to mimic desktop application's network footprint.

   If protocol is [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) you can record the associated requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). See [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) article for more details.

   If the desktop application uses different [network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) you will need to intercept the requests originating from the application using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and depending on the protocol(s) being used choose appropriate Samplers or Plugins or [come up with your own plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)
2. In case you need just to capture loading/rendering time of a single instance you can go for desktop automation tools/frameworks like [Appium](http://appium.io) or [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/). In this case you don't need JMeter at all or if you prefer you can add Appium/ldtp/whatever Java-based tool you choose libraries to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) for automating opening the application and user activities measuring time in-between actions and end-to-end time.

Answer (score 0):

Think architecturally for your app.  What is the next upstream component in your application architecture?  What does this suggest about the communication model between the thick client and the next upstream architectural component?

Does your tool support recording or reproducing this communications model?

Architecture is a foundation skill for performance testing.